# Date picker is not showing in some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox and I applied javascript datepicker function, but the datepicker will appear in some browsers and in some browsers it will only show an empty text box. Any ideas how Can I solve it?

```js
  $(function() { 
      $('#start').datepicker({ minDate: 0,dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',firstDay: 6});
      
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 

    
   


    <input type="text" id="start" size="25" name="meting_date" autocomplete="off" value="<?PHP echo isset($_POST['meting_date'])?$_POST['meting_date']:""; ?>" />
```

Comment: Please see error in browser console log.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="start" size="25" name="meting_date" autocomplete="off" value="<?PHP echo isset($_POST['meting_date'])?$_POST['meting_date']:''; ?>" />
```